# Difference between classes java.rmi.registry.Registry and java.rmi.Naming

Tags: java, rmi, naming, rmiregistry

What is the difference between the `Registry` class and `Naming` class.

In my application I am using `Registry` class. But I want to know about `Naming` class and its uses ?

Comment: `Naming` uses `Registery` internally.

Answer (score 15):

The difference is that `Naming` is a utility class with static methods, while `Registry` is a remote interface. Unsurprisingly, `Naming` calls `Registry` internally. Note that the `name` arguments you pass to `java.rmi.Naming` are in URL format, and include the location of the registry, whereas with `java.rmi.registry.Registry`, the `name` is just the name.

For example, you would call something like this:

```
Naming.rebind("//host/objName", myObj);
```

whereas with `Registry`, you need an existing handle on the registry object, and you'd call:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("host");
registry.rebind("objName", myObj);
```

So `Naming` is really just a convenience class that saves you having to look up the `Registry` manually - it performs the registry lookup and rebind in one step.