# Java RMI connection error: Not connecting to localhost

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to connect to my localhost when running my application, but for some reason it tries to connect to an ip address other than my localhost.

Below is the error message I am getting.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17rTH.png)

I have looked at my hosts file and is mapped like below:

[hostsfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEDK1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are manually creating the `Registry` you could change the line *14* and *17* to

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

registry.bind("fileService", fs);
```

On the other hand `Naming.rebind` suppose to default the host to `localhost` but you could specify it anyway

```
Naming.rebind("//localhost/fileService", fs)
```

thought in that case the line with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry` is not necessary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630329/difference-between-classes-java-rmi-registry-registry-and-java-rmi-naming it gives some detail on these alternatives

Comment: great that worked thank you. Any idea as to why the first method wasn't working as I was following my lecturers notes and that above main method worked for other people in my class

Comment: honestly not sure, in your code i think it was not necessary the `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);`, maybe that was causing some conflict, it could also be that in some version of java `Naming,rebind` doesn't have the default host as localhost